# Footer div acting up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a footer on my website that I want submitted text to be in a field, but for some reason two of my divs aren't getting along, as you can see in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfFun/1/).

All the CSS for the footer is:

```
.footer {
  background-image: url('debut_dark.png');
  color: white;
  width: 900px;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3px;

  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

And I can't find whats wrong with it.

Comment: Can you provide details, even an image, of what it is you actually want to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the `.contentdata` div properly .. you had `<div>` instead of `</div>` and that meant that `.footer` was inside `.contentdata` messing the dimensions.

```
<div class="contentdata">
   <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/PfFun/3/

Comment: This is also very verbose CSS. I would compress some of the declarations to: `margin: auto;` and `padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;`.

Comment: @IanAtkin, indeed... i was only responding to the actual problem.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't taking issue with your (correct IMHO) answer. Just the super-verbose CSS of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width from the `.footer` CSS.

```
.footer {
background-image: url('debut_dark.png');
color: white;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 3px;

padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Just guessing since you've not explained how it's supposed to look.

Comment: Do you mean `.footer` instead of `#footer`?

Comment: Where are you seeing `#footer`?

Comment: @Skaught Valiant attempt in light of no real explanation, but I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - yup, meant `.footer` .... @IanAtkin - agreed just a stab in the dark. Looks like Gaby is correct.